# How can i save this multiple page scraping in to a csv with just one header and no index, with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

The output i get is a csv without header, thats my problem
If I remove header=False o i set it to header=True i get a header for every page is screped.

so please if anyone can help me to reolve this using pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

pages = [0, 10 ,20, 30]

for page in pages:
    source = requests.get('https://guru.pucp.edu.pe/questions?start={}'.format(page))

    soup = BeautifulSoup(source.content, 'html.parser')
    quest_list = soup.find('div', class_='qa-q-list')

    q_items = quest_list.find_all('div', class_='qa-q-item-main-meta-stats')

    q_description = [item.find('a').get_text() for item in q_items]
    q_when = [item.find('span', {'class' : 'qa-q-item-when-data'}).get_text() for item in q_items]
    q_user = [item.find('span', {'class' : 'qa-q-item-who-data'}).get_text() for item in q_items]
    q_points = [item.find('span', {'class' : 'qa-q-item-who-points-data'}).get_text() for item in q_items]
    q_category = [item.find('span', {'class' : 'qa-q-item-where-data'}).get_text() for item in q_items]

    question_data = pd.DataFrame(
        {

            'question_description' : q_description,
            'when_created' : q_when,
            'user_name' : q_user,
            'question_points' : q_points,
            'question_category' : q_category,

        })
     
        print(question_data)
        question_data.to_csv('question_data.csv', mode='a', header=False, index=False)
```

thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the first page as is, with headers. For all following pages, set header to False.

```
if page == 0:
    question_data.to_csv('question_data.csv', index=False)
else:
    question_data.to_csv('question_data.csv', mode='a', header=False, index=False)
```